# How to design a *desired signal* for Lyapunov stability analysis?

Tags: stability

How to design a *desired signal* for Lyapunov stability analysis?

Like given in this paper:

http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/elektrik/issues/elk-15-23-3/elk-23-3-8-1212-29.pdf

Comment: Maybe book this helps - https://tinyurl.com/y8s77qpe

Comment: The paper is about adaptive gain rules used in adaptive filters incorporating penalty terms. The interesting thing to me is the similarities to regularization terms introduce in robust filtering and more recently sparse sensing. I didn’t see anything obviously connected to signal design. Perhaps you could explain how that paper relates to your question. I don’t see how this is an example